# Mapping a junction table with additional data in C# with NHibernate

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, nhibernate-mapping

Let's say I have a Parent and Child table, and a ParentChild table that maintains the relationships between them.

Parent class:

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual int ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Deleted { get; set; }

     public Parent()
     {
       _children = new HashedSet<Child>();
     }

     protected ISet<Child> _children;

     public virtual ISet<Child> children
     {
         get { return _children; }
         protected set { _children = value; }
     }
}
```

Child class:

```
public class Child
{
    public virtual int ChildId { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Deleted { get; set; }

     public Child()
     {
       _parents = new HashedSet<Parent>();
     }

     protected ISet<Parent> _parents;

     public virtual ISet<Parent> parents
     {
         get { return _parents; }
         protected set { _parents = value; }
     }
}
```

and the ParentChild class:

```
public class ParentChild 
{
    public virtual int ParentChildId { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual Child Child { get; set; }
    public virtual int DisplayOrderIndex { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

How would I map these so that I can do an update on the parent object that will also update the junction table with the additional data (not just parent/child id) and the Child table.

For now, I'm doing:

Parent Map

```
public ParentMap()
{
    Table("Parent");
    Id(x => x.ParentId);
    Map(x => x.Deleted);
    HasMany(x => x.ParentChild)
        .Table("Parent_Child")
        .KeyColumn("ParentID")
        .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
        .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
        .LazyLoad();
}
```

Child Map

```
public ChildMap()
{
    Table("Child");
    Id(x => x.ChildId);
    Map(x => x.Deleted);
    HasMany(x => x.ParentChild)
        .Table("Parent_Child")
        .KeyColumn("ChildID")
        .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
        .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
        .LazyLoad();
}
```

ParentChild Map

```
public ParentChildMap()
{
    Table("Parent_Child");
    Id(x => x.ParentChildId, "Parent_ChildID");
    References(x => x.Parent, "ParentID");
    References(x => x.Child, "ChildID");
    Map(x => x.DisplayOrderIndex);
    Map(x => x.Deleted);
}
```

But when I pull from the Parent repository, the Child in the ParentChild collection of the Parent object is a Castle.Proxy instead of a Child type.

How should this mapping be done to achieve the desired result?

Comment: `References(x => x.Child, "ChildID").Not.LazyLoad()`?